# Не хочет писать значение в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день,
Есть скрипт которое пингует все айпи адреса в столбце "ip_address", нужно чтобы после пинга отчеты писал в столбец "status". Т.е. если компьютер находится онлайн, в столбец "status" писать значение 1, а если оффлайн значение 0. Пример базы:
[image: Вот этот]

Чтобы не сделал никак не хочет писать эти значение. Вот мой скрипт:

```
include('db.php');
foreach($test as $value){
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0) {
        $status = 1;
        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO 'test' ('$value->status')" ."VALUES('{$status}');";
        mysql_query($insert_sql);

     }else{ 
    $status = 0;
    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO 'test' ('$value->status')" ."VALUES('{$status}');";
    mysql_query($insert_sql);
}
    }
```

а в db.php просто подключение к базе

Comment: `INSERT INTO 'test'` - почему здесь `test`? Надо же было в `devices` вставку делать? А откуда пришел массив `$test`? Из той же таблицы? Т.е. ip из этого массива всегда есть в таблице? Если всегда, то почему `insert`, если надо `update`? Или ip в массиве `$test` не всегда могут присутствовать в таблице? И что хранится в `$value->status`? Самый верный способ найти ошибку - научиться отлаживать код. Один из возможных вариантов - выводите запрос, который не срабатывает и ручками выполняете его в консоли `mysql`. Если запрос возвращает ошибку, значит не так формируете `sql`

Comment: "WHERE ip_address = '$value->ip_address'" Где это?

Comment: Через пару часов ожидаю увидеть в **обновлённом тексте вопроса** (выше) *хранимую процедуру* с именем `UpdateIpStatus`. Потом продолжим разговор ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема на 100% в динамически собранной строке.
Вместо попытки записи в базу, выведите на экран `$insert_sql` и увидите ошибку.

Скорее всего пропущена какая-нибудь кавычка, нарушается constraint на уровне таблицы или есть другая ошибка, которая на "всплывает" во время исполнения.

**UPD:**
я н очень знаком с диалектом mysql, но мне кажется что проблема вот здесь: 
`INSERT INTO test ('')VALUES('1')`

Откуда база узнает в **какую конкретно колонку** писать значение 1? Почему не указано имя колонки? Неужели трудно явно написать имя колонки `INSERT INTO test ('status')VALUES('1')`?

Знатоки mysql поправят меня. Быть может, ваш синтаксис такое допускает. Хотя я с трудом себе представляю, как диспетчер выполнения запросов разберется в какую колонку писать значение в варианте `INSERT INTO test ('')VALUES('1')` при существовании нескольких колонок одного и того же типа.

**UPD2:**
Записанное в базу оператором `INSERT INTO test ('status') VALUES('1')` является смысловой чушью, так как в базе появится просто пустая запись, содержащая единицу в поле status. Но не понятно, к какому конкретно IP будет относиться эта запись. Поэтому в базу нужно писать пару `ip_address` и `status`. И хорошо бы еще предварительно проверять наличие IP-адреса в таблице. Если адреса не существует, то мы его *добавляем* (`INSERT`). А если он существует, то *обновляем* (`UPDATE`). Выглядеть это должно так:

```
declare @ip_addr varchar(15)
declare @status bit

if exists (select * from test where ip_address = @ip_addr)
    /* адрес в БД уже есть, значит выполняем обновление */
    update test set
    status = @status
    where ip_address = @ip_addr

else
    /* адреса нет в базе, значит добавляем его */
    insert into test(ip_address, status) values(@ip_addr, @status)
```

Comment: 1) скорее всего не туда добавляют 2) такие записи уже есть, потому и не будут обновляются 3) не понятно что хранится в `$value->status`, скорее всего там далеко не название столбца 4) кавычки вокруг имени таблицы и столбца в `mysql` не нужны, это выдаст ошибку

Comment: @BOPOH, да-да... ты совершенно прав. Мы одну и ту же идею по сути выразили. Люди стремятся сразу писать в базу _неизвестночто_, предварительно не выведя это на экран и не проверив как это ваще выглядит.

Comment: вывел $insert_sql , выходит вот что:
INSERT INTO `test` ('')VALUES('1');INSERT INTO `test` ('')VALUES('0');
по моему он хочет писать эти значении в test , а не на status

Comment: @TriSTaR ну? Так ошибка видна? Просто скопируй выдачу на экран в редактов запросов mysql и попробуй эти запросы исполнить.

Comment: @TriSTaR дополнил ответ этими соображениями.

Comment: Написал так как вы поругали меня )
Но на базу ничего не пишет, а сам то хочет писать... посмотрите пожалуйста мой ответ ниже

Comment: @TriSTaR оператор `INSERT` просто вставляет в БД строчку с полем `status` равную 1 или 0. **Больше он ничего не делает**. Для того, чтобы *вставлять* логическую пару IP/status нужно делать так: `INSERT INTO (IPAddr, status) VALUES ('192.168.1.1', '0')`. Вам следутет почитать документацию о разнице операторов `INSERT` и `UPDATE`.

Comment: @TriSTaR в БД должна записываться *логическая пара* ip_address и status. Эта пара должна рассматриваться как целостная запись. Друг без друга эти поля - просто набор символов.

Comment: Блин, запутался есть же... Слишком запорно для новичка...

Comment: **Интерфейс**, не могли бы вы написать сам скрипт, брав пример из моих скриптов, если это вам не предоставит труда. пожалуйста

Comment: @TriSTaR, вам когда в дневник двойку ставили у дневника был владалец? Думаю, был. То есть по логике, двойку ставили не какому-то абстрактному и безымянному объекту, а вам, человеку с именем и фамилией. Так же и здесь. Когда вы вносите просто единицу а таблицу, как система может в дальнейшем понять с каким конкретно IP-адресом ее ассоциировать? Никак. Для этого используется табличный вид: яблоко - фрукт; цуккини - овощ; 192.168.1.10 - онлайн. Информацию надо класть в БД в соответствии с логикой.

Comment: @TriSTaR, нет. Код мы здесь не пишем и не отлаживаем. Это противоречит правилам сообщества. Для написания кода есть фрилансеры, которые охотно помогут вам за вознаграждение. На StackOverflow участники помогают другим участниками искать неточности и ошибки в коде. Тут помогают тем, кто самостоятельно исследует проблемную область, стремится разобраться и найти решение.

Comment: `if ($result == 0) {
        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO (IPAddr, status) VALUES ('$value->ip_address', '1')";
     } else {
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO (IPAddr, status) VALUES ('$value->ip_address', '0')";` 
Так?

Comment: @TriSTaR, да, это один из способов. Но он не проверяет наличие уже существующего адреса в базе. Через пару дней у ваш таблица будет забита кучей *одинаковых* IP-адресов и система будет продолжать туда адреса складывать.

Comment: @TriSTaR, давайте так: вы разбираесь с новым для вас вопросом - как создать на mysql **хранимую процедуру**, принимающую два параметра. Я а посодействую вам в ее написании.

Comment: @TriSTaR, изучите вот эту ссылку: http://www.cyberguru.ru/database/mysql/stored-procedures.html и потом продожим. Дальше все зависит от вас.

Comment: `if ($result == 0) { $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO (IPAddr, status) VALUES ('$value->ip_address', '1')"; } else { $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO (IPAddr, status) VALUES ('$value->ip_address', '0')";`
вот это хоть и работает, но на базу же не пишет О.о

Comment: @TriSTaR ничего пока работать не будет. Пока мы не напишем правильный код. Начните со ссылки выше. Через пару часов жду текст *хранимой процедуры*. Потом продолжим.

Comment: Окей сэр :) Только мне сейчас домой пора, рабочее время закончилось, ближе к вечеру дома зайду, и прочту обезятельно. Потом отпишусь тут...

Comment: Вы не могли бы лучше какой нить контактные данные оставить?

Comment: @TriSTaR Take your time, Sir :) Спокойно и неторопливо изучите материал по написанию хранимой процедуры. Как только ее напишем, будет вам правильное и изящное решение вопроса. *"лучше уметь писать хранимые процедуры, чем не уметь их писать"* (с) я

Comment: прочёл я статью внимательно, но почти что не понял.. Ц.т. : _**"Думаю хоть какие-то навыки программирования у вас есть, так что покажу всего лишь синтаксис."**_ Т.к. у меня мало навыков в области PHP и MysQL, я недавно начал их изучать. Но босс поручил вот такую геморойную задачу, Я конечно бы мог просто взять к примеру компьютеры по пинговать их и сразу вывести отчет, но на это у меня уходит уму времени, пока он всех пингует браузер стоит с загрузкой...

Comment: А я 2 ого выхожу на отпуск :(

Answer (score 0):

Имя таблицы не так 'table' а так `table`.

```
include('db.php');
foreach($test as $value){
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);
    $status = ($result == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO `test` ('$value->status') " . " VALUES('{$status}')";
    mysql_query($insert_sql);
}
```

Comment: Sergynyo, ваш скрипт не помог :(
не подскажите где может быть ошибка?

Comment: `INSERT INTO `test` ('') VALUES('1');` этого нету `$value->status` попробуй написать туда название поля, судя по твоему скришоту это "status". `$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO test ('status') " . " VALUES('{$status}')";`

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста мой ответ выше (с рисунком), работает скрипт но в базе значений нету

Answer (score 0):

Для начала посмотри что в `mysql_error()` и скинь сюда.

И код можно упросить до:

```
include('db.php');

foreach ($test as $value) {
    exec("ping -c 4 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);

    $status = $result == 0 ? 1 : 0;

    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO 'test' ('$value->status') VALUES('{$status}');";
    mysql_query($insert_sql);
}
```